# Laravel Stormpath Social Login Error

Tags: laravel-5, stormpath

I am using Laravel 5.1 and Stormpath for User management.

I followed [this documentation](https://docs.stormpath.com/client-api/product-guide/latest/social_login.html) to implement google login

1. Configuring Your Social Provider = DONE

I created project in Google Console and in **“Authorized redirect URIs”** I've added
`https://{DNS-LABEL}.apps.stormpath.io/authorize/callback`

1. Create a Stormpath Social Directory = DONE
2. Initiate Social Login - In my form when I click on Google Sign In it redirects to

   ```
   https://{DNS-LABEL}.apps.stormpath.io/?response_type=stormpath_token&
   account_store_href=https://api.stormpath.com/v1/directories/{id}
   &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost
   ```

and returns

```
{"status":404,"message":"Resource not found."}
```

As per [this documentation](https://docs.stormpath.com/php/product-guide/latest/auth_n.html#authn-google):

1. The user clicks on a “Login with Google” link pointing at your application’s `/authorize` endpoint
2. Stormpath handles the login to Google and redirects the user back to your app with a Stormpath Token JWT response

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't stormpath redirecting to the google login page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the URL that you are creating is missing the `/authorize` part.  If you update your URL to be

`https://{DNS-LABEL}.apps.stormpath.io/authorize?response_type=stormpath_token&
account_store_href=https://api.stormpath.com/v1/directories/{id}
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost`

It should begin working for you.

In a future release of the PHP SDK (which powers the laravel integration), we will be able to generate this URL for you.

If you are using our Stormpath/Laravel integration, the views provided will automatically handle social logic for you.  If you are doing this from scratch, it may be worth a look at https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-laravel

-Brian

Comment: When I send the `JWTResponse` to `/oauth/token` in order to get back OAuth 2.0 Access and Refresh tokens, why is it returning me `Missing grant_type value` even though in the POSTFIELDS I have set `grant_type => stormpath_token`